# Could a person extend their life by having a living blood supplied organ donor?

Tags: science-based, hard-science, law, life, health

An old person and young blooded close match person or clone to get some youth back? With a constant flow of fresh blood the older person the donor is not just donating blood but adding virtually all new organs to the patients but in retrospect it would be taxing to the donor. More than a blood transfusion you are hooked up most of the day and the donor body repairs many things over a period of time that a blood transfusion alone cannot do.

What if the patient hooks up to a clone who is genetically designed to beat cancer and could that rid cancer they may have? What if they just hooked up while sleeping and wake feeling great?

[image]

Comment: You want to be a vampire, and wonder if it will actually work.

Comment: Why is this being down voted?

Comment: @Cognisant, lack of research effort? Blood transfusions are a thing for decades, and nobody is rejuvenated thanks to them.

Comment: Not a WB question, just (another !) "What if ... ?" question dumped in WB.

Comment: "Experiments" like this are real life. Also, at best it is a story set in a world, not building a fictional world. At worst, it  is just another "no Stack accept this so I'll dump it on worldbuilding".

Comment: @Mołot  That is completely unfair and this has not been done on a regular basis as common practice except for in mice. Maybe we need a what if site.

Comment: @Muze Please feel free to take up the task of creating a What-If.SE!! I for one would welcome such a move if only to clear this Stack from all the non-worldbuilding gunk that seems to be clogging this forum. Also, the criticism you've received is totally fair: blood transfusions are  a fact of modern medicine. No one has ever become young again after a blood transfusion, marrow transplant or even multivisceral organ transplantation.

Comment: @L.Dutch In that very same sentence I explained that it doesn't repair the body, I'll admit that was the wrong word to use but I can't help but wonder about the motives behind you pedantry.

Comment: @Muze you gain +5 rep per upvote on a question and -2 per downvote. for questions you need to get 5 downvotes per 2 upvotes for you to not gain rep on a question. i don't have the rep or addon to see the vote counts on the question itself but looking to your rep for the day for this question it was +20/-16 meaning that you got 4 upvotes and 8 downvotes which would total -4 as a question score while you gain only +4 rep from the question

Comment: @L.Dutch after your comment I researched and made revisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly, there was an experiment of people "hooking up" a young mouse to the blood flow of an old mouse and it did work rejuvenating the old one (while doing the reverse of the young one). Not all the effects of ageing were affected, mind.

> In recent years, researchers studying mice found that giving old animals blood from young ones can reverse some signs of aging, and last year one team identified a growth factor in the blood that they think is partly responsible for the antiaging effect on a specific tissue—the heart. Now, that group has shown this same factor can also rejuvenate muscle and the brain.

Quote from here: https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2014/05/young-blood-renews-old-mice

There are also experiments that refute this:

> When two mice are sutured together, a technique called parabiosis, blood is not the only thing that is exchanged in this setup; organs are also shared, so old mice get access to younger lungs, thymus-immune system, heart, liver and kidneys. In surgical suturing it takes weeks to a month for the effects of blood to take place and the precise timing is not actually known. Nor is the precise amount of the exchanged blood.

[...]

> In many of these experiments, older mice that received younger blood saw either slight or no significant improvements compared to old mice with old blood. Young mice that received older blood, however, saw large declines in most of these tissues or organs.

[...]

> “Under no circumstances did young blood improve brain neurogenesis in our experiments” [...] “Old blood appears to have inhibitors of brain cell health and growth, which we need to identify and remove if we want to improve memory.”

Source: http://news.berkeley.edu/2016/11/22/young-blood-does-not-reverse-aging-in-old-mice-uc-berkeley-study-finds/

So, your setup will probably not work very well. Better to wait for science to do more experiments and discover what causes some of the rejuvenating effects and how to replicate them medicinally.

Comment: Really good answer with real life experiments.

Comment: @Liquid on mice not people

Comment: @Muze Mice are often the step before human experimentation. Their biology is somewhat comparable to ours and this, among other reasons, is why mice are so used in general. So yea, I think it's relevant.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very old idea.  It comes from the early misunderstanding of blood in the body as "that stuff that gives life".  The logic is understandable, even if wrong, as when you "lose all of your blood" you die.

Replacing old blood with "young blood" will not significantly alter your age any more than getting a skin graft from a younger person, or a kidney transplant, or any other kind of tissue transplant.  The majority of your body is still the same age.

If by some means, you could transplant most of your body with a younger one, then it raises some interesting points.  First, you would be provably younger than you were before, possibly extending life.  Second you would be inherently less "you" and more "your donor(s)"

Finally, the "everything but the brain" transplant won't be a long-term solution either.  Brains age too.

Answer (score 2):

## No

Blood requires a lot of chemical treatment before a transfusion can be done. Even then it's not the best mix for you - you are getting only some filtered parts from donations. You would be dilluting your blood.

Even hemodialysis would be better than that, and it's a last stand procedure to keep people without functional kidneys from dying.

So no, don't even consider it. There is nothing realistic about that Mad Max blood transfusion setup.

Comment: +1 about that MadMax reference, I actually thought it was possible!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_transfusion#/media/File:Direct-blood-transfusion.jpg - As recently as World War II direct human to human transfusions was reality.

Answer (score 1):

As we age our bodies undergo cascading degradation, basically when one organ starts failing its failure to do it's job optimally affects every other organ in the body. Now our bodies are designed to be able to cope with this to some degree, there's a lot of redundancy, you can still live with one lung and one kidney, but the damage is cumulative and that damage can cause more damage. When a doctor tells you someone is dying of old age this is what they mean, the patient's condition is progressing into multiple organ failure because the damage is already so severe the body can no longer maintain itself.

Injecting an old person with young (compatible) blood may have temporary rejuvenating effects but that's like changing the oil in your car's engine, it doesn't repair the engine it just gives it a temporary reprieve from the ineffectiveness of the old oil.

If you have some wealthy old bastard hooked up to the cardiovascular system of a young clone that won't make him younger but it could slow his rate of aging and therefore it would be a form of life extension, but it won't save him if he's dying of cancer, the cancer will just spread to the clone and kill the clone too.